# Repeating specific regex pattern

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I have a regex pattern:

```
boost::regex regex = "@ABC-\\d+"
```

which means pattern starting with @ABC- and followed by one or more digits.
I want this pattern to be able to match this pattern one or more times that is:

```
boost::regex regex = "@ABC-\\d+@ABC-\\d+@ABC-\\d+@ABC-\\d+etc, etc"
```

Comment: [`R"(^(@ABC-\d+)+$)"`](https://regex101.com/r/qO5oO3/1) - is that what you need?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew hi, yep, that's why I've asked this question. Thanks by the way it works. Make it an answer and I will accept it. Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a **[grouping construct](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)** and apply a **[quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)** to it, and use `^` and `$` **[anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)** to make sure the whole string is matched against the pattern:

Example:

```
R"(^(@ABC-\d+)+$)"
```

or - with a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group) that will never create a capture inside the memory buffer (this grouping construct is meant to only group subpatterns to match string sequences):

```
R"(^(?:@ABC-\d+)+$)"
     ^^
```

If the string can be empty, replace the last `+` with `*`: `R"(^(@ABC-\d+)*$)"`.

Note that in C++, raw string literals are preferred when declaring regular expression patterns to avoid excessive backslashes.